# How do I group items separated by a 0 in a column using mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following structure:

```
id,center,shelf_id,occupied,remaining
1,East,1_1_1,1,3
2,East,1_1_2,1,1
3,East,1_1_3,1,0
4,East,1_1_4,1,0
5,East,1_1_5,1,2
6,East,1_2_1,1,1
7,East,1_2_2,1,0
8,East,1_2_3,0,4
9,East,1_2_4,0,4 
10,East,1_2_5,0,4
11,East,1_3_1,0,4
12,East,1_3_2,0,4
13,East,1_3_3,0,4
14,East,1_3_4,0,0
```

I would like to aggregate by remaining where remaining is not 0.

The above example should return a table with a commas delimited shelf_id and remaining with a total of remaining that looks like:

```
shelf_id
1_1_1, 1_1_2
remaining
3,1
total
4

shelf_id
1_1_5, 1_2_1
remaining
2,1
total
3

shelf_id
1_2_3, 1_2_4, 1_2_5, 1_3_1, 1_3_2, 1_3_3
remaining
4,4,4,4,4,4
total
24
```

I am using MariaDB 10.2.31.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
WITH 
cte1 AS
(
SELECT shelf_id, remaining, SUM(remaining = 0) OVER (ORDER BY id) group_num
FROM test
)
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(shelf_id) shelf_id,
       GROUP_CONCAT(remaining) remaining,
       SUM(remaining) total
FROM cte1
WHERE remaining != 0
GROUP BY group_num;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e0f7a0d9069291c3942eb529b2afaaa0)

Comment: Thank you again Akina! Very much appreciated :)